# MVC RedirectToAction() any way to pass object to the target action?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

The populated catList is always Count=0 when the code jumps to CreateProduct() so I take it it does not get delivered. 
Considering RouteValueDictionary does not do this ? Any other way?

```
       public ActionResult GetCats(int CatID)
    {

        List<Category> catList = new List<Category>();

        if (CatID >= 0 )
        {

            catList = context.Categories.Where(x => x.PCATID == CatID).ToList();
        }


        return RedirectToAction("CreateProduct", "Admin", new { catList });
    }





public ActionResult CreateProduct(List<Category> catList) {      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually trying to use controllers to do data access.

Move the "GetCats" data retrieval into your business layer (Service object, Repository, whatever suits you).

Then, CreateProduct will need to be there twice (2 signatures). One with no parameters in which you are going to call "GetCats" from your business layer and send it to the view.

The other implementation is going to be the flagged with the HttpPostAttribute and will contain in parameters all the necessary information to create a cat.

That's all. Simple and easy.

Answer (score 2):

You could place any items that you need in `TempData` then call `RedirectToAction`.

Answer (score 1):

[RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction.aspx) simply returns a ["302"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) code to the browser with the URL to redirect to. When this happens your browser performs a GET with that URL.

Your RouteValues need to be simple. You can't really pass complex object or collections using a route value.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't care about the browser url changing you could just

`return CreateProduct(catList`)

Comment: I agree return a view or partial view instead of a redirect to action. render actions and redirect to actions when overused can affect application performace.