# How can I use RedirectToAction to pass an object to a new Action in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, redirect, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this scenario.

A form (ForexPayment) is filled by a user, he/she then clicks **Next**.

I then show new page (ForexPaymentConfirmation) with just the labels and values (i.e. a read-only confirmation page) so he/she can either **Submit** or **Cancel** the request.

My questions:

- How do i use `return RedirectToAction("ForexPaymentConfirmation");` to pass an object containing the Payment Information from one view to the next?
- One option would be to store the Payment Information in the Current Session and reclaim it on the new page ...
- Is there a better way of achieving this?

Searching through SO, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7599952/44080 which states:

> You are actually trying to use controllers to do data access.

But in this case, I have not saved the payment yet, I need to preview on a different View, before saving.

*With WebForms, i'd simply unhide a panel on the same page to achieve this.*

Comment: If you object contains only properties which are value types then you can use `return RedirectToAction("ForexPaymentConfirmation", yourModel);` and add a parameter in the GET method for the model. But it will fail of any properties are complex objects or collections, and it will create an ugly query string and it throw an exception if the length of the query string is exceeded. Use `Session` or better, save the model with a flag and pass its ID to the GET method

Comment: by complex you mean object property right?

Comment: If you model is (say) `public class Project` and it contains a property (say) `public ProjectCategory Category { get; set; }` where `ProjectCategory` is a class, then it will fail.

Comment: Thanks. I'll simply use session then. Post this as the answer, with the explanation, i'll accept it.

Comment: Be wary of using `Session`. It can expire so when the user clicks 'Submit', there is a risk the object may no longer exist.

Comment: This is very good. It would force the user to login again if he has been idle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to pass a simple object to a GET method using

```
return RedirectToAction("ForexPaymentConfirmation", model);
```

However, internally this creates an ugly query string including all the names and values of your properties

```
../ForexPaymentConfirmation?somePropertyName=someValue&anotherPropertyName=AnotherValue.....
```

It will only work if your model contains properties which are value types (`int`, `bool` `DateTime` etc) or `string`. If any properties are complex objects or collections, binding will fail. In addition you could easily exceed the query string limit and throw and exception.

Its unclear why you need this pattern (as opposed to saving the model and then in the 'details' view having a 'delete' button' in case the user changes their mind), but you need to persist the model somewhere. You can use `Session` (but you should not use `TempData`), but its always better to persist it to some form of repository, for example to a database (could be another 'temporary' table) or serialize it to an xml file so that you can retrieve it in the GET method. Another option would be to store it in the permanent table but include a bit flag (say `bool IsPending`) that you could set when you 'Confirm', and in the case of 'Cancel', just delete the table row.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload of `RedirectToAction` method.

```
protected internal RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues
)
```

How about passing your object as routeValue?

```
return RedirectToAction("MyAction", "MyController", new RouteValueDictionary(paymentInfo)
```

and using it in your action like

```
public ActionResult SearchJob(PaymentInfopaymentInfo)
{
     Return View();
}
```

Or you can also use `TempData["paymentInfo"]` to pass data from controller to controller.

As Stephen suggested. Read data using `Keep()` if you are using `TempData` to persist it's value for next request. Or your can use `Session` and nullify it when data is no longer needed.

Comment: Do not use `TempData` for this. Once its read in the GET method its disposed and wont be available again when the 'Confirm' button is clicked, and the user could refresh the browser causeing it all to fail (unless `.Keep()` is used)